# need help to build caml query with 7 parameters in where clause

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Want to build caml query for 7 parameters in where clause.
Please share the link if you have to build caml query.

Thanks in Advance,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's only one parameter, use the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx).